# Difference between iOS 7 and iOS 5.1 App behavior when in background

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ipad, ios7

What are the differences in iOS 5.1 & 7.0 in the aspect App behavior when it is in background?

My problem is when switching to other app and switching back (let's say after 5 min / 30 mins) to my app, I am getting server error "connection lost". That was not happening with iOS 5.1, but happening in iOS 7.

I think there is something with the iPad running in the background in different way on iOS 7...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you do when your application goes into the background?  Are you using any of the special background modes to keep your app alive when put in the background?  Specifically, under OS 5.1, is your app being terminated and relaunched on switching back?

Comment: the app runs the same way on both OS and it's not terminated.
the app send request to webserver every 20 seconds ~.

and in - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
I cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget and performSelector again.

on OS 5.1 that works good.
on OS 7.0, not everytime, but often, I get "connection lost" when I switch back.
if seems that somthing still running on ios7.0 when going background..but I'm not sure. maybe I need to cancel requests when going background, but I want to understand the diffrences between the OS

Comment: iOS7 is much more liberal with letting applications run in the background than prior versions of the OS.  You probably should consider canceling the requests or closing the connections when going into the background explicitly.

Comment: @gaige
thanks..
I think I will handle it when app become active and when catching the error. I prefer not to doing any action when user leave this, specially if it's only for fews seconds.